# Rotating around axes with tikz-3dplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, animate, tikz-3dplot

I'm a bit confused by the following code.  I would think that the following would produce an animation of rotating 90-degrees around the x-, y-, and z-axes, but the first part of the animation looks like it rotates around the z-axis and not the x-axis.  Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{animate}  % Animations
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing,
   backgrounds, positioning, fit, shapes.geometric}

\def\drawaxes{
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay, controls, poster=first]{60}
      \multiframe{90}{iFrame=0+1}{
        \tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
          \draw (-5cm, -3cm) rectangle (5cm, 3cm);

          \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\iFrame}{0}{0}
          \begin{scope}[color=red,
                        tdplot_rotated_coords,
                        xshift=-3cm,scale=0.25]
            \drawaxes
          \end{scope}

          \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{\iFrame}{0}
          \begin{scope}[color=red,tdplot_rotated_coords,scale=0.25]
            \drawaxes
          \end{scope}

          \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{\iFrame}
          \begin{scope}[color=red,
                        tdplot_rotated_coords,
                        xshift=3cm,scale=0.25]
            \drawaxes
          \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }
    \end{animateinline}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I certainly I have not much experience with tikz but have you tried to add `%` at the end of `\multiframe{90}{iFrame=0+1}{%` .... because I think that something confuse the compiler

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the % didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're are stating is because of the convention adopted by Jeff Hein in the tikz-3dplot.

As he explained, he chose the Euler z-y-z convention (I guess it's the most widely used convention in astrophysics).

> Syntax: \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{α}{β }{γ }
>
> Parameters: 
>   α The angle (in degrees) through which the rotated frame is rotated about the world z axis. 
>   β The angle (in degrees) through which the rotated frame is
>   rotated about the world y axis. γ The angle (in degrees) through which
>   the rotated frame is rotated about the world z axis.

You want to do rotations around z, y and x axis witch are usually called nautical angles (or Tait-Bryan, or Cardan, or zyx Euler angles...).

A good solution to changed the convension used is to redefine the rotation matrix used by \tdplotsetrotatedcoords as suggested in [Navigation system coordinates in tikz-3dplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27515/navigation-system-coordinates-in-tikz-3dplot) .

Answer (score 2):

Here's a work-around in case anyone else runs into the same problem.  Use `\tdplotsetmaincoords{rotationX}{0}`, plot the rotation, then switch back to `\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}` to plot as normal.  For example, in the code I posted above, replace

```
      \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{\iFrame}{0}
      \begin{scope}[color=red,tdplot_rotated_coords,scale=0.25]
        \drawaxes
      \end{scope}
```

with

```
      \tdplotsetmaincoords{\iFrame}{0}
      \begin{scope}[color=red,tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.25]
        \drawaxes
      \end{scope}
      \tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}
```

It may not be the most elegant solution, but it seems to have done the trick for the animation I was trying to make.

Comment: be careful, not all of your rotations are in the positive way. `tdplotsetrotatedcoords` and `tdplotmaincoords` work in opposite ways.