# Complex 3D drawings with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I've already produced the following picture by means of `TikZ`.
[image]
To do it, I modified the Sudoku example found [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/) as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{5}{6}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,every node/.style={minimum size=1cm},on grid]

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=-0.5},yslant=-0.5]
  \shade[right color=gray!10, left color=black!50] (0,0) rectangle +(3,3);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=0.5},yslant=0.5]
  \shade[right color=gray!70,left color=gray!10] (3,-3) rectangle +(3,3);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1]
  \shade[bottom color=gray!10, top color=black!50] (6,3) rectangle +(-3,-3);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=-0.5},yslant=-0.5]
  \foreach \i in {.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  \foreach \j in {.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  {
  \node at (\i,\j) {$+$};
  }

  \foreach \i in {0,3}
  \foreach \j in {.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  {
  \node at (\i,\j) {$+$};
  }

  \foreach \i in {.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  \foreach \j in {0,3}
  {
  \node at (\i,\j) {$+$};
  }

  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,3}
  \foreach \j in {.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  {
  \node at (\i,\j) {$+$};
  }

  \draw (0,0) grid (3,3);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=0.5},yslant=0.5]  
  \foreach \i in {3.5,4.5,...,5.5}
  \foreach \j in {-2.5,-1.5,...,-.5}
  {
  \node at (\i,\j) {$+$};
  }

  \foreach \i in {3,6}
  \foreach \j in {-2.5,-1.5,...,-.5}
  {
  \node at (\i,\j) {$+$};
  }

  \foreach \i in {3.5,4.5,...,5.5}
  \foreach \j in {-3,0}
  {
  \node at (\i,\j) {$+$};
  }

  \draw (3,-3) grid (6,0);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1]  
  \foreach \i in {3.5,4.5,...,5.5}
  \foreach \j in {0.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  {
  \node at (\i,\j) {$+$};
  }

  \foreach \i in {3,6}
  \foreach \j in {0.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  {
  \node at (\i,\j) {$+$};
  }

  \foreach \i in {3.5,4.5,...,5.5}
  \foreach \j in {0,3}
  {
  \node at (\i,\j) {$+$};
  }

  \draw (3,0) grid (6,3);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=-0.5},yslant=-0.5]
  \foreach \i in {.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  \foreach \j in {.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  {
  \draw[<-] (\i,\j) -- +(-.2,-.2);
  }

  \foreach \i in {0,3}
  \foreach \j in {.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  {
  \draw[red,<-] (\i,\j) -- +(-.2,-.2);
  }

  \foreach \i in {.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  \foreach \j in {0,3}
  {
  \draw[red,<-] (\i,\j) -- +(-.2,-.2);
  }

  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,3}
  \foreach \j in {.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  {
  \draw[red,->] (\i,\j) -- +(.2,0);
  }

  \foreach \i in {.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  \foreach \j in {0,1,...,3}
  {
  \draw[red,->] (\i,\j) -- +(0,.2);
  }  
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=0.5},yslant=0.5]  
  \foreach \i in {3.5,4.5,...,5.5}
  \foreach \j in {-2.5,-1.5,...,-.5}
  {
  \draw[->] (\i,\j) -- +(.2,-.2);
  }

  \foreach \i in {3,6}
  \foreach \j in {-2.5,-1.5,...,-.5}
  {
  \draw[red,->] (\i,\j) -- +(.2,-.2);
  }

  \foreach \i in {3.5,4.5,...,5.5}
  \foreach \j in {-3,0}
  {
  \draw[red,->] (\i,\j) -- +(.2,-.2);
  }

  \foreach \i in {3,4,...,6}
  \foreach \j in {-2.5,-1.5,...,-.5}
  {
  \draw[red,->] (\i,\j) -- +(.2,0);
  }

  \foreach \i in {3.5,4.5,...,5.5}
  \foreach \j in {-3,-2,...,0}
  {
  \draw[red,->] (\i,\j) -- +(0,.2);
  }  
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1]  
  \foreach \i in {3.5,4.5,...,5.5}
  \foreach \j in {0.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  {
  \draw[->] (\i,\j) -- +(.2,.2);
  }

  \foreach \i in {3,6}
  \foreach \j in {0.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  {
  \draw[red,->] (\i,\j) -- +(.2,.2);
  }

  \foreach \i in {3.5,4.5,...,5.5}
  \foreach \j in {0,3}
  {
  \draw[red,->] (\i,\j) -- +(.2,.2);
  }

  \foreach \i in {3,4,...,6}
  \foreach \j in {0.5,1.5,...,2.5}
  {
  \draw[red,->] (\i,\j) -- +(.2,0);
  }

  \foreach \i in {3.5,4.5,...,5.5}
  \foreach \j in {0,1,...,3}
  {
  \draw[red,->] (\i,\j) -- +(0,-.2);
  }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I had to use multiple `scope` environments with the same `yslant` and `slant` in order to obtain the layers to correctly overlay each other.

Nevertheless I'm not so happy with the picture, since I could not easily change the view.
Is there a more effective way to draw such a picture in TikZ (or, more generally, in LaTeX)?
I would like to use TikZ (and not to produce the picture with external programs, e.g. MATLAB), since I should insert legend, labels, a other text stuff in such a picture.
Furthermore, I suspect `pgfplots` is the answer, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT:** I think a complete answer can come from those who fully understand [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/need-help-creating-a-3d-cube-from-a-2d-set-of-nodes-in-tikz) by @Tom Bombadil.

Comment: *"...since I could not easily change the view"* What do you mean? If you want to "rotate" it... :P

Comment: Oh, yes, I used the word "view" to make you think to `view={⟨h⟩}{⟨v⟩}` option of `pgfplots`' `axis` environment.

Comment: Take a look at this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262290/representing-general-transformations-on-a-3d-grid-using-tikz/262409#262409

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I've been able to draw such a thing using pgfplots:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
       xmin=0,
       xmax=1,
       ymin=0,
       ymax=1,
       zmin=0,
       zmax=1,
       axis equal,
       ticks=none,
       hide axis,
     ]
%lower face, drawn first as it will be hidden
     \addplot3[black,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0,
       quiver/v=0,
       quiver/w=0.1,
       -{stealth[]},
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
     ]{0};
     \addplot3[red,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0.1,
       quiver/v=0,
       quiver/w=0,
       -stealth,
       samples=4,
       domain y=0.16666:0.8333,
       samples y=3,
       domain=0:1,
     ]{0};
     \addplot3[red,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0,
       quiver/v=-0.1,
       quiver/w=0,
       stealth-,
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
       samples y=4,
       domain y=0:1,
     ]{0};
%hidden right face, drawn first as it will be hidden
     \addplot3[black,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0,
       quiver/v=0,
       quiver/w=0.1,
       -{stealth[]},
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
     ](x,1,y);
     \addplot3[red,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0.1,
       quiver/v=0,
       quiver/w=0,
       -stealth,
       samples=4,
       domain y=0.16666:0.8333,
       samples y=3,
       domain=0:1,
     ](x,1,y);
     \addplot3[red,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0,
       quiver/v=0,
       quiver/w=0.1,
       -stealth,
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
       samples y=4,
       domain y=0:1,
     ](x,1,y);
%hidden left face, drawn first as it will be hidden
     \addplot3[black,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0,
       quiver/v=0,
       quiver/w=0.1,
       -{stealth[]},
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
     ](0,x,y);
     \addplot3[red,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0,
       quiver/v=-0.1,
       quiver/w=0,
       stealth-,
       samples=4,
       domain y=0.16666:0.8333,
       samples y=3,
       domain=0:1,
     ](0,x,y);
     \addplot3[red,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0,
       quiver/v=0,
       quiver/w=0.1,
       -stealth,
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
       samples y=4,
       domain y=0:1,
     ](0,x,y);
      % faces
     \addplot3[surf,
       color=black!40,
       faceted color=black!80,
     domain=0:1,
   domain y=0:1,
   samples=4,
   samples y=4,
 ]
     (x,0,y);
     \addplot3[surf,
       color=black!40,
       faceted color=black!80,
     domain=0:1,
   domain y=0:1,
   samples=4,
   samples y=4,
 ]
     {1};
     \addplot3[surf,
       color=black!40,
       faceted color=black!80,
     domain=0:1,
   domain y=0:1,
   samples=4,
   samples y=4,
 ]
     (1,x,y);
     %upper face
     \addplot3[black,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0,
       quiver/v=0,
       quiver/w=0.1,
       -{stealth[]},
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
     ]{1};
    \addplot3[mark=x,
      only marks,
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
     ]{1};
     \addplot3[red,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0.1,
       quiver/v=0,
       quiver/w=0,
       -stealth,
       samples=4,
       domain y=0.16666:0.8333,
       samples y=3,
       domain=0:1,
     ]{1};
     \addplot3[red,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0,
       quiver/v=0.1,
       quiver/w=0,
       -stealth,
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
       samples y=4,
       domain y=0:1,
     ]{1};
     %left face
    \addplot3[black,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0,
       quiver/v=-0.1,
       quiver/w=0,
       {stealth[]}-,
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
     ](x,0,y);
    \addplot3[mark=x,
      only marks,
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
     ](x,0,y);
     \addplot3[red,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0.1,
       quiver/v=0,
       quiver/w=0,
       -stealth,
       samples=4,
       domain y=0.16666:0.8333,
       samples y=3,
       domain=0:1,
     ](x,0,y); 
     \addplot3[red,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0,
       quiver/v=0,
       quiver/w=0.1,
       -stealth,
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
       samples y=4,
       domain y=0:1,
     ](x,0,y);
   %right face
    \addplot3[black,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0.1,
       quiver/v=0,
       quiver/w=0,
       -{stealth[]},
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
     ](1,x,y);
    \addplot3[mark=x,
      only marks,
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
     ](1,x,y);
     \addplot3[red,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0,
       quiver/v=0.1,
       quiver/w=0,
       -stealth,
       samples=4,
       domain y=0.16666:0.8333,
       samples y=3,
       domain=0:1,
     ](1,x,y); 
     \addplot3[red,/pgfplots/quiver,
       quiver/u=0,
       quiver/v=0,
       quiver/w=0.1,
       -stealth,
       samples=3,
       domain=0.16666:0.8333,
       samples y=4,
       domain y=0:1,
     ](1,x,y);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which leads to the following fig:

[image]

There are still a few differences (markers are not aligned, no shadings) but it's manageable. The more complicated thing is to optimize the code which is a mess^^

And I don't know how to manage the order of the faces so that they hide in the good order.