# Extra whitespace around tikz-3dplot? How to fix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, tikz-3dplot

Can someone explain me (MWE derived from [this 3D Box example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262409/74646)):

- **Why below MWE produces whitespace on the left in the second picture?** This is caused by the 2 set-`coords`.  If you comment them out, the space is gone, but the box does not look the same anymore
- How can I  make the **coordinates local instead of global?** The problem is that they are now directly in the `tikzpicture` parameters, so I cannot move them inside the `tikzpicture` environment. Well you can move them inside, but then it does not work anymore (second picture will then looks the same as the first picture).

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{125}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0} %<- rotate around (z,y,z)
\begin{document}
\framebox { 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_rotated_coords,
                    cube/.style={very thick,black},
                    grid/.style={very thin,gray}]%
\draw[cube,fill=green!10] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,0,0) -- cycle;%
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\framebox{
% If you comment these 2 lines out the space is gone (but not correctly rotated anymroe)
\tdplotsetmaincoords{35}{125}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0} %<- rotate around (z,y,z)
% ---
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_rotated_coords,
                    cube/.style={very thick,black}]%
\draw[cube,fill=green!10] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,0,0) -- cycle;%
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you end a line with a `{` or `}` you add a space.  Alas, tikz-3dplot does this a lot.  `\tdplotsetmaincoords` only only adds 2 spaces, but `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords` adds a bunch.  The tikz parser ignores spaces.

BTW, it seems that tikz does its own garbage collection, so setting global pgfkey values is not that simple.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{125}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0} %<- rotate around (z,y,z)
\begin{document}
\framebox {%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_rotated_coords,
                    cube/.style={very thick,black},
                    grid/.style={very thin,gray}]%
\draw[cube,fill=green!10] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,0,0) -- cycle;%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\framebox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,cube/.style={very thick,black}]%
\tdplotsetmaincoords{35}{125}%
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0}%<- rotate around (z,y,z)                      
\begin{scope} [tdplot_rotated_coords]                 
\draw[cube,fill=green!10] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,0,0) -- cycle;%
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```