# How to fit the filling pattern to the z axis in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello as you can see in the following image on the right is the outputted image and my desired image is hand drawn on the left. How do I make the fill pattern of the sine/cosine curve on the yz plane (horizontal) go vertical in the yz plane rather than vertical in the xy plane

[image: Output image on the right, desired image with lines in the yz plane on the left]

Here is the code for you to have a look at

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (10.5,0,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5);
\draw[pattern=vertical lines] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) cos (2,0,0) sin (3,-1,0) cos (4,0,0) sin (5,1,0) cos (6,0,0) sin (7,-1,0) cos (8,0,0) sin (9,1,0) cos (10,0,0);
\draw[pattern=vertical lines] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) cos (2,0,0) sin (3,0,-1) cos (4,0,0) sin (5,0,1) cos (6,0,0) sin (7,0,-1) cos (8,0,0) sin (9,0,1) cos (10,0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: something other than use north east lines, so that if I decide to rotate the view it will still appear correctly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an alternative to Zarko's nice answer with shorter code and a more wave-like wave, i.e. the first maximum as wide as the other ones.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (10.5,0,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5);
\draw[pattern=vertical lines] (0,0,0) -- plot[variable=\x,domain=0:10,samples=72] (\x,{cos(72*\x)},0)
-- (10,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[pattern=north east lines] (0,0,0) -- plot[variable=\x,domain=0:10,samples=72] (\x,0,{cos(72*\x)}) -- (10,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Just saw your comment under Zarko's nice answer. Probably Zarko means the `tikz-3dplot` package, the link is correct, and here is an animation illustrating his point.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,5,...,355}{
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{\X}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use as bounding box] (-5.5,-3) rectangle (5.5,3);
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.5]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (10.5,0,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5);
\draw[pattern=vertical lines] (0,0,0) -- plot[variable=\x,domain=0:10,samples=72] (\x,{cos(72*\x)},0)
-- (10,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[pattern=north east lines] (0,0,0) -- plot[variable=\x,domain=0:10,samples=72] (\x,0,{cos(72*\x)}) -- (10,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to have more flexible rotations, you may want to look at both answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438688/121799).

**2ND EDIT**: Without patterns it might be look a bit better even.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,5,...,355}{
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{\X}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use as bounding box] (-5.5,-3) rectangle (5.5,3);
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.5]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (10.5,0,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5);
\draw (0,0,0) -- plot[variable=\x,domain=0:10,samples=72,smooth] (\x,{cos(72*\x)},0)
-- (10,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0,0) -- plot[variable=\x,domain=0:10,samples=72,smooth] (\x,0,{cos(72*\x)}) -- (10,0,0) -- cycle;
\foreach \Y in {0,0.2,...,10}
{\draw[thin] (\Y,0,0) -- (\Y,{cos(72*\Y)},0);
\draw[thin] (\Y,0,0) -- (\Y,0,{cos(72*\Y)});}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not want to post spoilers in the chat room, but here a preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rimNv.png

Comment: @samcarter Soo nice of you!! (Perhaps add `whiskers` and `teeth` ? ;-)

Comment: I'll save all the advanced options for the tikzmarmots talk at TUG19 :)

Comment: @samcarter Oh my god, this means that I should not have given away my crystal ball, otherwise I'd have known that... ;-)

Comment: @marmot, yes, i meant `tikz-3dplot` (link has correct name) :-). very good animations! (+1) !

Comment: @Zarko True, you gave the correct link, I should have checked! I updated (and +1 of course!).

Answer (score 7):

is close enough?

[image]

for available patterns see "TikZ & PGF manual, 3.0.1a", page 666:  there is also listed <`north east lines` which is closed to what you looking for:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (10.5,0,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5);
\draw[pattern=vertical lines] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) cos (2,0,0) sin (3,-1,0) cos (4,0,0) sin (5,1,0) cos (6,0,0) sin (7,-1,0) cos (8,0,0) sin (9,1,0) cos (10,0,0);
\draw[pattern=north east lines] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) cos (2,0,0) sin (3,0,-1) cos (4,0,0) sin (5,0,1) cos (6,0,0) sin (7,0,-1) cos (8,0,0) sin (9,0,1) cos (10,0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there something that does it in the plane so that even if I rotate the image in 3D it still works?

Comment: @sabhoque, check `tikz-3D` (https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot?lang=en).

Answer (score 4):

I defined three new patterns, `x lines`, `y lines`, and `z lines` that work well with the `tikz-3dplot` package (actually, the `tikz-3dplot` with at least the `\tdplotsetmaincoords` command is needed for these patterns to function well).

You can check the code to see how it works, but don't hesitate to ask me :)

PS. I also used @marmot's method of plotting the sine waves such that they remain good looking when rotated in 3D.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\makeatletter
\newlength\zlines@x
\newlength\zlines@y
\newlength\ylines@x
\newlength\ylines@y
\newlength\xlines@x
\newlength\xlines@y

\pgfmathsetmacro\linesep{5}

\tikzset{
    x lines vector/.code={
        \pgfextractx\xlines@x{#1}
        \pgfextracty\xlines@y{#1}
        \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\xlines@x == 0 || abs(\xlines@x) < abs(\xlines@y) || \xlines@y == 0,"\linesep pt","\linesep*\xlines@x/\xlines@y")}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\xlines@width{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\xlines@x == 0 || abs(\xlines@x) > abs(\xlines@y) || \xlines@y == 0,"\linesep pt","\linesep*\xlines@y/\xlines@x")}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\xlines@height{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\xlines@vector@x{10*\xlines@x}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\xlines@vector@y{10*\xlines@y}
    },
    y lines vector/.code={
        \pgfextractx\ylines@x{#1}
        \pgfextracty\ylines@y{#1}
        \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\ylines@x == 0 || abs(\ylines@x) < abs(\ylines@y) || \ylines@y == 0,"\linesep pt","\linesep*\ylines@x/\ylines@y")}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\ylines@width{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\ylines@x == 0 || abs(\ylines@x) > abs(\ylines@y) || \ylines@y == 0,"\linesep pt","\linesep*\ylines@y/\ylines@x")}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\ylines@height{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\ylines@vector@x{10*\ylines@x}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\ylines@vector@y{10*\ylines@y}
    },
    z lines vector/.code={
        \pgfextractx\zlines@x{#1}
        \pgfextracty\zlines@y{#1}
        \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\zlines@x == 0 || abs(\zlines@x) < abs(\zlines@y) || \zlines@y == 0,"\linesep pt","\linesep*\zlines@x/\zlines@y")}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\zlines@width{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\zlines@x == 0 || abs(\zlines@x) > abs(\zlines@y) || \zlines@y == 0,"\linesep pt","\linesep*\zlines@y/\zlines@x")}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\zlines@height{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\zlines@vector@x{10*\zlines@x}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\zlines@vector@y{10*\zlines@y}
    },
    x/.forward to=/tikz/x lines vector,
    y/.forward to=/tikz/y lines vector,
    z/.forward to=/tikz/z lines vector,
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\xlines@vector@x,\xlines@vector@y,\xlines@width,\xlines@height]{x lines}
{\pgfpoint{-0.6*\xlines@width}{-0.6*\xlines@height}}
{\pgfpoint{0.6*\xlines@width}{0.6*\xlines@height}}
{\pgfpoint{\xlines@width}{\xlines@height}}
{
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\xlines@vector@x}{-\xlines@vector@y}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\xlines@vector@x}{\xlines@vector@y}}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.3pt}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\ylines@vector@x,\ylines@vector@y,\ylines@width,\ylines@height]{y lines}
{\pgfpoint{-0.6*\ylines@width}{-0.6*\ylines@height}}
{\pgfpoint{0.6*\ylines@width}{0.6*\ylines@height}}
{\pgfpoint{\ylines@width}{\ylines@height}}
{
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\ylines@vector@x}{-\ylines@vector@y}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\ylines@vector@x}{\ylines@vector@y}}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.3pt}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\zlines@vector@x,\zlines@vector@y,\zlines@width,\zlines@height]{z lines}
{\pgfpoint{-0.6*\zlines@width}{-0.6*\zlines@height}}
{\pgfpoint{0.6*\zlines@width}{0.6*\zlines@height}}
{\pgfpoint{\zlines@width}{\zlines@height}}
{
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\zlines@vector@x}{-\zlines@vector@y}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\zlines@vector@x}{\zlines@vector@y}}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.3pt}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \foreach \rotation in {30,50,...,360}{
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{\rotation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (-11,-4) rectangle (11,4);
        \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0}
        \begin{scope}[xscale=1,tdplot_main_coords,tdplot_rotated_coords]
            \draw[->,red]   (0,0,0) -- (10.5,0,0);
            \draw[->,green] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0);
            \draw[->,blue]  (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5);

            \draw[pattern=y lines] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0)  --plot[domain=0:2.25*360,samples=30,smooth] ({10*\x/(2.25*360)},{cos(\x)},{0}) -- cycle;
            \draw[pattern=z lines] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1)  --plot[domain=0:2.25*360,samples=30,smooth] ({10*\x/(2.25*360)},{0},{cos(\x)}) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]