# Easy way to generate Rubik's cube diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf

Taking inspiration from [Playing around with a Rubik's Cube in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444812/playing-around-with-a-rubiks-cube-in-tikz), I want to generate diagrams of Rubik's cubes that look like this

[image][image][image][image]

Using a solution from [Playing around with a Rubik's Cube in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444812/playing-around-with-a-rubiks-cube-in-tikz), I was able to generate this diagram

[image]

My question is what is the best way to modify the code so I can quickly generate the diagrams in the above graphic? Something like a command `\cube{....}`? But even I am not sure how you can specify the colour info in this manner. Use a symbol for each colour? G - green, B - blue etc. So there are 27 square faces in this diagram, so does that mean you need 27 arguments? And if you leave it blank then it will display a gray tile? I would appreciate any advice the best way to code this in LaTeX. My ultimate goal is to make over 100 diagrams like the ones above. So if it was possible to make a really efficient code to generate the diagrams that would be amazing.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro\radius{0.1}
\newcommand{\frontcolor}{red}
\newcommand{\sidecolor}{blue}
            \tdplotsetmaincoords{55}{135}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \clip (-3,-2.5) rectangle (3,2.5);
                \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
                    \filldraw [canvas is yz plane at x=1.5] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
                    \filldraw [canvas is xz plane at y=1.5] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
                    \filldraw [canvas is yx plane at z=1.5] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
                    \foreach \X in {-1.5,-0.5,0.5}{
                        \foreach \Y in {-1.5,-0.5,0.5}{
                            \draw [thick,canvas is yz plane at x=1.5,shift={(\X,\Y)},fill=\sidecolor] (0.5,0) -- ({1-\radius},0) arc (-90:0:\radius) -- (1,{1-\radius}) arc (0:90:\radius) -- (\radius,1) arc (90:180:\radius) -- (0,\radius) arc (180:270:\radius) -- cycle;
                            \draw [thick,canvas is xz plane at y=1.5,shift={(\X,\Y)},fill=\frontcolor] (0.5,0) -- ({1-\radius},0) arc (-90:0:\radius) -- (1,{1-\radius}) arc (0:90:\radius) -- (\radius,1) arc (90:180:\radius) -- (0,\radius) arc (180:270:\radius) -- cycle;
                            \draw [thick,canvas is yx plane at z=1.5,shift={(\X,\Y)},fill=yellow] (0.5,0) -- ({1-\radius},0) arc (-90:0:\radius) -- (1,{1-\radius}) arc (0:90:\radius) -- (\radius,1) arc (90:180:\radius) -- (0,\radius) arc (180:270:\radius) -- cycle;
                        }
                    }
                \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's a neat question, and here is a proposal for an answer. The colors are stored in an array called `\myarray`, which determines the colors of the cells. The relation between entry (the index starts at 0) and cell is illustrated by this example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\newif\ifshowcellnumber
\showcellnumbertrue
\begin{document}
\definecolor{R}{RGB}{202,65,55}
\definecolor{G}{RGB}{151,216,56}
\definecolor{B}{RGB}{51,72,237}
\definecolor{W}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{X}{RGB}{65,65,65}

\newcommand{\TikZRubikFaceLeft}[9]{\def\myarrayL{#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9}}
\newcommand{\TikZRubikFaceRight}[9]{\def\myarrayR{#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9}}
\newcommand{\TikZRubikFaceTop}[9]{\def\myarrayT{#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9}}
\newcommand{\BuildArray}{\foreach \X [count=\Y] in \myarrayL%
{\ifnum\Y=1%
\xdef\myarray{"\X"}%
\else%
\xdef\myarray{\myarray,"\X"}%
\fi}%
\foreach \X in \myarrayR%
{\xdef\myarray{\myarray,"\X"}}%
\foreach \X in \myarrayT%
{\xdef\myarray{\myarray,"\X"}}%
\xdef\myarray{{\myarray}}%
}
\TikZRubikFaceLeft
        {X}{X}{X}
        {X}{X}{X}
        {X}{X}{G}
\TikZRubikFaceRight
        {W}{X}{X}
        {R}{G}{G}
        {X}{G}{G}
\TikZRubikFaceTop
        {X}{X}{R}
        {R}{R}{G}
        {R}{R}{X}
\BuildArray
%\def\myarray{{"X","X","B","X","G","X","R","R","X","X","X","X","G","X","B","B","X","X","G","B","R","X","R","B","X","X","X"}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\radius{0.1}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{55}{135}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \clip (-3,-2.5) rectangle (3,2.5);
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \filldraw [canvas is yz plane at x=1.5] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
  \filldraw [canvas is xz plane at y=1.5] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
  \filldraw [canvas is yx plane at z=1.5] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
  \foreach \X [count=\XX starting from 0] in {-1.5,-0.5,0.5}{
   \foreach \Y [count=\YY starting from 0] in {-1.5,-0.5,0.5}{
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{\XX+3*(2-\YY)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\myarray[\Z]}
    \draw [thick,canvas is yz plane at x=1.5,shift={(\X,\Y)},fill=\mycolor] (0.5,0) -- ({1-\radius},0) arc (-90:0:\radius) -- (1,{1-\radius}) arc (0:90:\radius) -- (\radius,1) arc (90:180:\radius) -- (0,\radius) arc (180:270:\radius) -- cycle;
    \ifshowcellnumber
     \node[canvas is yz plane at x=1.5,shift={(\X+0.5,\Y+0.5)}] {\Z};
    \fi 
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{2-\XX+3*(2-\YY)+9}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\myarray[\Z]}
    \draw [thick,canvas is xz plane at y=1.5,shift={(\X,\Y)},fill=\mycolor] (0.5,0) -- ({1-\radius},0) arc (-90:0:\radius) -- (1,{1-\radius}) arc (0:90:\radius) -- (\radius,1) arc (90:180:\radius) -- (0,\radius) arc (180:270:\radius) -- cycle;
    \ifshowcellnumber
     \node[canvas is xz plane at y=1.5,shift={(\X+0.5,\Y+0.5)},xscale=-1] {\Z};
    \fi 
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{2-\YY+3*\XX+18}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\myarray[\Z]}
    \draw [thick,canvas is yx plane at z=1.5,shift={(\X,\Y)},fill=\mycolor] (0.5,0) -- ({1-\radius},0) arc (-90:0:\radius) -- (1,{1-\radius}) arc (0:90:\radius) -- (\radius,1) arc (90:180:\radius) -- (0,\radius) arc (180:270:\radius) -- cycle;
    \ifshowcellnumber
     \node[canvas is yx plane at z=1.5,shift={(\X+0.5,\Y+0.5)},xscale=-1,rotate=-90] {\Z};
    \fi 
    }
   }
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\TikZRubikFaceLeft
    {X}{X}{X}
    {X}{X}{X}
    {X}{G}{X}
\TikZRubikFaceRight
    {X}{X}{X}
    {X}{B}{X}
    {W}{B}{X}
\TikZRubikFaceTop
    {X}{R}{X}
    {X}{W}{X}
    {X}{W}{G}
\BuildArray
\showcellnumberfalse
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \clip (-3,-2.5) rectangle (3,2.5);
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \filldraw [canvas is yz plane at x=1.5] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
  \filldraw [canvas is xz plane at y=1.5] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
  \filldraw [canvas is yx plane at z=1.5] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
  \foreach \X [count=\XX starting from 0] in {-1.5,-0.5,0.5}{
   \foreach \Y [count=\YY starting from 0] in {-1.5,-0.5,0.5}{
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{\XX+3*(2-\YY)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\myarray[\Z]}
    \draw [thick,canvas is yz plane at x=1.5,shift={(\X,\Y)},fill=\mycolor] (0.5,0) -- ({1-\radius},0) arc (-90:0:\radius) -- (1,{1-\radius}) arc (0:90:\radius) -- (\radius,1) arc (90:180:\radius) -- (0,\radius) arc (180:270:\radius) -- cycle;
    \ifshowcellnumber
     \node[canvas is yz plane at x=1.5,shift={(\X+0.5,\Y+0.5)}] {\Z};
    \fi 
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{2-\XX+3*(2-\YY)+9}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\myarray[\Z]}
    \draw [thick,canvas is xz plane at y=1.5,shift={(\X,\Y)},fill=\mycolor] (0.5,0) -- ({1-\radius},0) arc (-90:0:\radius) -- (1,{1-\radius}) arc (0:90:\radius) -- (\radius,1) arc (90:180:\radius) -- (0,\radius) arc (180:270:\radius) -- cycle;
    \ifshowcellnumber
     \node[canvas is xz plane at y=1.5,shift={(\X+0.5,\Y+0.5)},xscale=-1] {\Z};
    \fi 
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{2-\YY+3*\XX+18}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\myarray[\Z]}
    \draw [thick,canvas is yx plane at z=1.5,shift={(\X,\Y)},fill=\mycolor] (0.5,0) -- ({1-\radius},0) arc (-90:0:\radius) -- (1,{1-\radius}) arc (0:90:\radius) -- (\radius,1) arc (90:180:\radius) -- (0,\radius) arc (180:270:\radius) -- cycle;
    \ifshowcellnumber
     \node[canvas is yx plane at z=1.5,shift={(\X+0.5,\Y+0.5)},xscale=-1,rotate=-90] {\Z};
    \fi 
    }
   }
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, if you replace `\showcellnumbertrue` by `\showcellnumberfalse`, the numbers are suppressed.

**EDITs**: Illustrated the relation between array index and cell (which is almost redundant now) and adjusted the color (big thanks to @manooooh!). I also used now the conventions of the `rubik` package, which I did not really know before seeing [Peter Grill's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459275/121799). The conventions are still slightly different since I refer to the faces as left, right and top. This is because this thingy can be rotated in some range, but left will always be left in that range. I also added some `%`, which were added in first in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459407/121799).

**ADDENDUM**: Encouraged by @LoopSpace's comment:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\newif\ifshowcellnumber
\showcellnumberfalse
\begin{document}
\definecolor{R}{RGB}{202,65,55}
\definecolor{G}{RGB}{151,216,56}
\definecolor{B}{RGB}{51,72,237}
%\definecolor{W}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{W}{RGB}{65,65,65}

\def\myarray{{"W","W","B","W","G","W","R","R","W","W","W","W","G","W","B","B","W","W","G","B","R","W","R","B","W","W","W"}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\radius{0.1}
\newcommand{\frontcolor}{red}
\newcommand{\sidecolor}{blue}
\foreach \X in {95,100,...,175}
{            \tdplotsetmaincoords{55}{\X}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \clip (-3,-2.5) rectangle (3,2.5);
                \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
                    \filldraw [canvas is yz plane at x=1.5] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
                    \filldraw [canvas is xz plane at y=1.5] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
                    \filldraw [canvas is yx plane at z=1.5] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
                    \foreach \X [count=\XX starting from 0] in {-1.5,-0.5,0.5}{
                        \foreach \Y [count=\YY starting from 0] in {-1.5,-0.5,0.5}{
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{\XX+3*(2-\YY)}
                        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\myarray[\Z]}
                            \draw [thick,canvas is yz plane at
x=1.5,shift={(\X,\Y)},fill=\mycolor] (0.5,0) -- ({1-\radius},0) arc
(-90:0:\radius) -- (1,{1-\radius}) arc (0:90:\radius) -- (\radius,1) arc
(90:180:\radius) -- (0,\radius) arc (180:270:\radius) -- cycle;
        \ifshowcellnumber
            \node[canvas is yz plane at x=1.5,shift={(\X+0.5,\Y+0.5)}] {\Z};
        \fi 
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{2-\XX+3*(2-\YY)+9}
                        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\myarray[\Z]}
                            \draw [thick,canvas is xz plane at
y=1.5,shift={(\X,\Y)},fill=\mycolor] (0.5,0) -- ({1-\radius},0) arc
(-90:0:\radius) -- (1,{1-\radius}) arc (0:90:\radius) -- (\radius,1) arc
(90:180:\radius) -- (0,\radius) arc (180:270:\radius) -- cycle;
        \ifshowcellnumber
            \node[canvas is xz plane at y=1.5,shift={(\X+0.5,\Y+0.5)},xscale=-1] {\Z};
        \fi 
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{2-\YY+3*\XX+18}
                        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\myarray[\Z]}
                            \draw [thick,canvas is yx plane at
z=1.5,shift={(\X,\Y)},fill=\mycolor] (0.5,0) -- ({1-\radius},0) arc
(-90:0:\radius) -- (1,{1-\radius}) arc (0:90:\radius) -- (\radius,1) arc
(90:180:\radius) -- (0,\radius) arc (180:270:\radius) -- cycle;
        \ifshowcellnumber
            \node[canvas is yx plane at z=1.5,shift={(\X+0.5,\Y+0.5)},xscale=-1,rotate=-90] {\Z};
        \fi 
                        }
                    }
                \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: According to the first image of OP the white cubes should be black.

Comment: Lovely, as always.  Can we tweak the cube to add perspective?  There's a question here somewhere about it.

Comment: @LoopSpace Yes. That is what `\tdplotsetmaincoords{55}{135}` does. And the question is most likely where the [answer that the OP and I build](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444812/playing-around-with-a-rubiks-cube-in-tikz) on is from.

Comment: Thank you @marmot this is really excellent. The package `rubik` has a really nice format for specifying the colours of the faces and generating the diagram of the cube. I was wondering if it is possible to get that sort of functionality with your TikZ method? The reason why your TikZ method is superior to the package `rubik` is because here we have full control over the viewing angle (I really need an isometric viewing angle). There seems to be no way to adjust the angle using `rubik` so your code is much better.

Comment: So my question is can we take `\myarray{...}` and make it into `\RubikFaceUp
        {X}{X}{X}
        {X}{X}{X}
        {X}{G}{X}` etc... Followed by a single command like    `\ShowCube{7cm}{0.7}{\DrawRubikCube}`. I guess you would save the `tikzpicture` code to generate the cube in the preamble.

Comment: @Sam I do not think that one can simply add the rubik code, but what one can certainly do is to fill the array with `\RubikFaceUp` and so on commands, such that these determine colors of the cells on the faces. However, I am wondering if you *really* want to name the commands in *precisely* the same way as the ones from an official package, or if we should call them, say,  `\TikZRubikFaceUp` and so on.

Comment: @marmot Yes the name is not important, yes I agree better to be different.

Comment: @Sam OK, I added something along these lines. Notice that the rubik conventions are not *precisely* adapted, but between the lines I believe to read that this is not too important. The reason why I did not adapt these is that "Front" is sort of ambiguous once one can rotate the thingy.

Comment: @marmot This works brilliantly! Yes, I like your notation of left and right :)

Answer (score 24):

There is also a [rubik](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/rubik?lang=en) package designed specifically for this. The  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) below generates the four cube positions shown in the question.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}%% load tikz BEFORE rubikcube
\usepackage{rubikcube}
%\usepackage{rubikrotation,rubikpatterns,rubiktwocube}% Related packages

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \RubikFaceUp
        {X}{X}{X}
        {X}{X}{X}
        {X}{X}{G}
    \RubikFaceRight
        {W}{X}{X}
        {R}{G}{G}
        {X}{G}{G}
    \RubikFaceFront
        {X}{X}{R}
        {R}{R}{G}
        {R}{R}{X}
   \ShowCube{7cm}{0.7}{\DrawRubikCube}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \RubikFaceUp
        {X}{X}{X}
        {X}{X}{X}
        {X}{G}{X}
    \RubikFaceRight
        {X}{X}{X}
        {X}{B}{X}
        {W}{B}{X}
    \RubikFaceFront
        {X}{R}{X}
        {X}{O}{X}
        {X}{O}{G}
   \ShowCube{7cm}{0.7}{\DrawRubikCube}
\end{minipage}

\par\medskip
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \RubikFaceRight
        {X}{X}{X}
        {G}{B}{X}
        {G}{B}{X}
    \RubikFaceFront
        {X}{X}{X}
        {X}{O}{R}
        {X}{O}{R}
   \ShowCube{7cm}{0.7}{\DrawRubikCube}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \RubikFaceUp
        {X}{X}{X}
        {G}{X}{X}
        {X}{X}{G}
    \RubikFaceRight
        {W}{X}{X}
        {X}{G}{G}
        {X}{G}{G}
    \RubikFaceFront
        {X}{X}{X}
        {R}{R}{X}
        {R}{R}{X}
   \ShowCube{7cm}{0.7}{\DrawRubikCubeRU}
\end{minipage}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you this is really interesting, I did not know of this package. I've had a look at the documentation and it seems there is no way to adjust the viewing angle so that it is 'isometric' like in my example? This is quite crucial to my use as the focus is on the edge between the front and right faces. This is for doing F2L diagrams. Don't know if anyone knows a way to adapt this package to making the viewing angle isometric?

Comment: @Sam: Try emailing the package authors. Might make sense to add that feature directly to the package.