# In tikz, why isn't the rectangle rotated like the collection of points?

Tags: tikz-pgf

By using `rotate around x` I can rotate a collection of points around axis X, but I can't seem to rotate a `rectangle`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around x=90]
  \draw rectangle (1,1);
  \draw[yshift=-20] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! I'd recommend using the `3d` library for that and then use `transform shape` in some `canvas is yz plane at x=0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot give a deep answer on *why* that is but the rectangle construction is AFAIK a simple `(point1) -| (point1) -| cycle`. And the `|-` does not get transformed normally. However, there are various possibilities to achieve what you seem to want. You see that the `rotate around` key is not as "efficient" as the `canvas is yx plane` key that comes with the `3d` library. Notice that there is a small bug in the `3d` library that has been fixed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799). Of course, with the `3d` library it is not straightforward to implement arbitrary rotations, however, that can be fixed by using the `tikz-3dplot` package. If you want to access all possible rotations, you may be interested in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438688/121799). There you can also find a way of achieving arbitrary rotations without even loading the `tikz-3dplot` package, but there is IMHO no reason not to load that package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around x=90,transform shape]
  \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \draw[yshift=-20,purple] (0,0) -| (1,1) -| cycle;  
  \draw[yshift=-40,blue] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
  \node[anchor=north west,minimum width=1cm,minimum
  height=1cm,draw,green!50!black] at (0,-2){};  
  \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,canvas is yx plane at z=0,transform shape]
  \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \draw[yshift=-40,blue] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
  \node[anchor=north west,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm,draw,green!50!black] at (0,-2){};  
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]